# Filter Azure Access Token based on Azure AD User Role

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory, access-token

I have a Spring Boot application where I'm trying to filter the incoming Access Token based on the roles defined in our Azure Active Directory. The Access Token validates correctly, but I seem unable to filter on the roles.

What am I missing? Do I need to add my own filtering of the incoming Access Token for Spring to detect the roles?

---

Debug output:

```
[nio-8444-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/v1/control/list
[nio-8444-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
[nio-8444-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to common.controller.ControlRestController#getControlList(Integer, Integer, String, String)
[nio-8444-exec-3] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET https://login.windows.net/common/discovery/keys
[nio-8444-exec-3] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
[nio-8444-exec-3] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
[nio-8444-exec-3] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [java.lang.String] as "application/json;charset=utf-8"
[nio-8444-exec-3] o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider  : Authenticated token
[nio-8444-exec-3] .o.s.r.w.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@f884058d, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[SCOPE_User.Read]]
[nio-8444-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /api/v1/control/list] with attributes [hasAnyRole('Role-1')]
[nio-8444-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Web Security Configurer:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class JWTSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("**").hasAnyRole("Role-1")
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
}
```

Dependencies in application.properties:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Example of Access Token payload:

```
{
  "aud": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/",
  "iat": 1637836195,
  "nbf": 1637836195,
  "exp": 1637840650,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "AVQAq/8TAAAA8y1Ih2o5+C1xcchX2nVt1PllQ8jEQGrO5iqhuS0sTQ75E7oB2wpYBV2nOHgv+gTfWjyKcd8pMAE/F6+QTQ2U8Q1Oz2mP1i9BCuG0rIyEj00=",
  "amr": [
    "pwd",
    "mfa"
  ],
  "appid": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "family_name": "Doe",
  "given_name": "John",
  "ipaddr": "x.x.x.x",
  "name": "Doe John",
  "oid": "b590b433-b825-4ff2-8efc-b705e8d41408",
  "onprem_sid": "S-1-9-25-2282756759-60046336-13015914-96287",
  "rh": "0.AXMAnEh5FnJct0a6Y5q5DEqtRKvm2tigXA1PmabHelrn8M5zAI8.",
  "roles": [
    "Role-1",
    "Role-2"
  ],
  "scp": "User.Read",
  "sub": "Se1ew9fPjO-ltCQBTEftFQBycjNRzD1YZ1aHqqerx-A",
  "tid": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "unique_name": "john@doe.com",
  "upn": "john@doe.com",
  "uti": "z_ugyP6aH1Sje8bFQl1rAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}﻿
```